# Match the Specific Child Attribute of Specific Parent Node XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to match and change the value of *displayHeight* attribute of the aspect name *x* in the following XML using XSL but the following XSL template changes all the displayHeight values. I need the following template to match the displayHeight attribute of only where the aspect name is x.

```
<xsl:template match="@value[parent::property[@name='displayHeight']]">
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="'Value Has Been Changed By XSL'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

**XML Source**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<a>
    <b>
        <aspect name="x">
           <properties>
                 <property name="displayHeight" value="600"/>
                 <property name="displayWidth" value="800"/>
            </properties>
         </aspect>
         <aspect name="y">
             <properties>
                    <property name="displayHeight" value="1280"/>
                    <property name="displayWidth" value="720"/>
                </properties>
         </aspect>
    </b>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:template match="aspect[@name = 'x']/properties/property[@name = 'displayHeight']/@value">
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="'Value Has Been Changed By XSL'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```